# URL working with & but not &amp;

Tags: php, url, file-get-contents, urlencode

I have this link which works fine.

```
http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/PropertyProfileOverviewServlet?boro=3&houseno=512&street=bedford%20ave&requestid=0&s=A03C41B885B461E4F46BD08866A7430E
```

I want to do the get the content of this URL but the issue is the `file_get_contents` content convert `&` to `&amp;`

```
http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/PropertyProfileOverviewServlet?boro=3&amp;houseno=512&amp;street=bedford%20ave&amp;requestid=0&amp;s=A03C41B885B461E4F46BD08866A7430E
```

Which doesn't work.

```
$url = "http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/PropertyProfileOverviewServlet?boro=3&houseno=512&street=bedford%20ave&requestid=0&s=A03C41B885B461E4F46BD08866A7430E";
$content = file_get_contents($url);
echo $content;
```

It generates error.

```
$url = "http://www.google.com";
$content = file_get_contents($url);
echo $content;
```

It works fine.

Comment: Use `html_entity_decode()`

Comment: "Issue is the file_get_contents content convert & to &amp;" - how do you figure?

Comment: Running the first snippet just gives me `HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden`

Comment: "It generates error." What error?

Comment: _“`file_get_contents` content convert `&` to `&amp;`”_ – why would it do that? That’s most certainly _not_ the issue. More likely that _you_ converted it, by saving that script file wrong or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without setting a `User-Agent` for the request, I get a 403 forbidden error.

This code works:

```
<?php

$url = "http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/PropertyProfileOverviewServlet?boro=3&houseno=512&street=bedford%20ave&requestid=0&s=A03C41B885B461E4F46BD08866A7430E";

$opts = array(
    'http' => array('header' => 'User-Agent: test'),
);

$ctx = stream_context_create($opts);

$content = file_get_contents($url, false, $ctx);
var_dump($content);
```

Looks like the site by default disallows the PHP user agent so you will need to specify one using the stream context or use another library like cURL to fetch the content.

This is a common problem when trying to use file_get_contents to fetch remote URLs.

Comment: Alternatively, `ini_set('user_agent', 'test');` before `file_get_contents()`.

Comment: Thank you @drew010 this is working like charm. I am also trying to get content from [link](http://a836-acris.nyc.gov/DS/DocumentSearch/BBLResult?hid_borough=2&hid_borough_name=BRONX&hid_block=2287&hid_block_value=2287&hid_lot=7&hid_lot_value=7&hid_doctype_name=All Document Classes&hid_max_rows=10&hid_page=1&hid_SearchType=BBL&hid_ISIntranet=N) which give me bad request but when i copy paste the url it works fine.

Comment: @user2986104 Looks like you need to call [`urlencode`](http://php.net/urlencode) on the URL you pasted.  When I ran it as `http://a836-acris.nyc.gov/DS/DocumentSearch/BBLResult?hid_borough=2&hid_borough_name=BRONX&hid_block=2287&hid_block_value=2287&hid_lot=7&hid_lot_value=7&hid_doctype_name=All&Document%20Classes&hid_max_rows=10&hid_page=1&hid_SearchType=BBL&hid_ISIntranet=N` it works.  Note the `%20` in `All Document Classes`